# Einstein Analytics Label Values are not changing?

Tags: json, einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

I have changed the labels in the XMD for my Einstein analytics Dashboard and these are not changing on the Columns in the data table, **is there a known issue with Formula Fields or something is the XMD that prevent the label value from being changed? Or is there another way?**

I was able to change many of the other field label values in the same Dataset. One is a date field the other is a formula field.

[image: XMD Change 1]

[image: XMD Change 2]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In XMD : you need to change it in the dimensions.

example

{
      "conditionalFormatting": {},
      "customActions": [],
      "customActionsEnabled": true,
      **"field": "Opportunity.CloseDate",**
      **"label": "Close Date",**
      "linkTemplateEnabled": true,
      "members": [],
      "recordDisplayFields": [],
      "salesforceActions": [],
      "salesforceActionsEnabled": true,
      "showInExplorer": false
    },

Comment: Sorry where is the xmd? is this the JSON file that we can download from data manager > dataflows & recipes ?

Comment: actually my bad, i found this link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_integrate_dataset_xmd.htm&type=5